# Custom textbox in expression

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I have made a simple calculator in expression blend 4. I am just learning to use this. I have made custom buttons and made them into controls, and I have text boxes that I made into controls. I opened the project in visual studio and created click event for the buttons and that works, however, I can not type into the text boxes. How do I make that happen?

Comment: Let's see the control template for your textbox.

Answer (score 0):

> Are you **define new control** or **create only new Template**?

If you **`define new control`** you must define a text-box as Content. (using template binding and set content value for text-box )
So If **you define new Template** and You Got mistake in it. let see your control and template!
(For More Help)